# Cross Site Publishing in SharePoint Online

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, publishing-page, cross-site-publishing, catalog

I was asked to test Cross Site Publishing features in SharePoint 2013 Online. I saved the Authoring site collection's (Used Team Site's Template since Product Catalog Template not avialable in SP Online) Pages library as a Catalog. When I connected that catalog in my Publishing site collection, 2 pages created automatically. `Category` Page is showing the content, but `CatelogItem` page is empty. How can I configure Content Search Web Part to show the Page Content of the Authoring Sites's page?

Can we show Authoring sites Pages libraries page content on the publishing site?

Is this possible in SharePoint Online Cross Site Publishing?

Comment: Cross-site publishing uses search, you need to wait till the crawl indexes. Also the two pages that got auto created are for a starting point and user should add content to it. More http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635883(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response Amal. Actually I was waited until its crawled(checked after 24 hrs). Simply What I want to know is, Is it possible to get Authoring Site's Specific Page Content/htmlcontent (Live in Page Library of Authoring Site and saved as a Catalog) by a Content Search web part added to the Publishing site's page? (Please note that these sites created in SharePoint 2013 Online and activated Cross site Publishing feature)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing I was able to show the HTML Content of the Authoring site's page by changing the Property Mappings of the Content Search Web Part. I used 'PublishingPageContentOWSHTML' as a manged property to do this.